# Búsqueda de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un query que me trae un dato en especifico que es el numero de transacción, lo he hecho de tal forma que pueda traer las transacciones de todas las cuentas que tiene un cliente, ligando la cuenta del cliente (que a su ves esta ligada a su identificación, por eso en los parámetros solo coloco las fechas e identificación del cliente y así trae todas las cuentas que tenga el cliente)

igualandola a todos los campos que contenga dicha cuenta en la tabla **Transacciones**

```
DECLARE @FechaInic DATE;
DECLARE @FechaFina DATE;
DECLARE @Identidad VARCHAR(25);

SET @FechaInic = '2017-01-01';
SET @FechaFina = '2021-09-29';
SET @Identidad = '08019017910309';



SELECT
DISTINCT a.Transaccion
INTO #Temporal1

FROM (
--****************************************************** Consulta 1 *******************************--
SELECT 
bp.BPId AS Transaccion
FROM dbo.Transacciones AS bp WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Contratos AS ccr1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccr1.NumeroContrato =bp.RelatedContractNumber AND ccr1.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1
INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c1 ON c1.ClientId=ccr1.ClientId

WHERE bp.FechaT BETWEEN @FechaInic AND @FechaFina AND bp.BPStatusId=10 
 AND (c1.TaxCode = @Identidad)     

 UNION ALL
 --****************************************************** Consulta 2 *******************************--
SELECT 
bp.BPId AS Transaccion

FROM dbo.Transacciones AS bp WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Contratos AS ccr1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccr1.NumeroContrato =bp.CorrespondingContractNumber AND ccr1.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1
INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c1 ON c1.ClientId=ccr1.ClientId

WHERE bp.FechaT BETWEEN @FechaInic AND @FechaFina AND bp.BPStatusId=10 
 AND (c1.TaxCode = @Identidad) 

 UNION ALL 
 --************************************************** Consulta 3 *******************************     (TARDA)
SELECT 
bp.BPId AS Transaccion
FROM dbo.Transacciones AS bp WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Contratos AS ccr1 ON ccr1.NumeroContrato =bp.OrderingAccount AND ccr1.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1
INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c1 ON c1.ClientId=ccr1.ClientId

WHERE bp.FechaT BETWEEN @FechaInic AND @FechaFina AND (c1.TaxCode=@Identidad) AND bp.BPStatusId=10

UNION ALL
--************************************************** Consulta 4 *******************************   (TARDA)
SELECT 
bp.BPId AS Transaccion
FROM dbo.Transacciones AS bp WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Contratos AS ccr1 ON ccr1.NumeroContrato =bp.BeneficiaryAccount AND ccr1.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1
INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c1 ON c1.ClientId=ccr1.ClientId

WHERE bp.FechaT BETWEEN @FechaInic AND @FechaFina AND (c1.TaxCode=@Identidad) AND bp.BPStatusId=10

UNION ALL
 --****************************************************** Consulta 5 *******************************--
SELECT 
bp.BPId AS Transaccion

FROM dbo.Transacciones AS bp WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.RelacionTransaccion AS bpcr ON bpcr.BPId = bp.BPId
INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c1 ON c1.ClientId=bpcr.ClientId

WHERE bp.FechaT BETWEEN @FechaInic AND @FechaFina AND bp.BPStatusId=10 
 AND (c1.TaxCode = @Identidad)
```

Todo funciona bien el tema es que quisiera mejorar la velocidad de la consulta ya que actualmente se tarda entre 7 a 8 minutos en generar la información, los he corrido individuales y he identificado los que se tardan mas (le coloque entre parentesis TARDA)

Cabe mencionar que los campos que no tardan tienen las siguiente estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estas son las que se tardan
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veo que las que No se tardan tienen el T_NAMEU, no se si sera eso,

Que podría hacer para acelerar la búsqueda? podría usar INDEX?

Comment: Cuando corres las consultas en SQLServer Management Studio, tienes la opción de incluír el plan de ejecución y ahí puedes ver recomendaciones de índices. Puedes empezar por ahí. Pero **cuidado**, en [este post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/11/the-problems-with-sql-servers-index-recommendations/), Brent Ozar nos alerta de posibles tropiezos al confiar ciegamente en estas sugerencias. También es posible que tu pregunta esté cerrada por pedir opiniones o ser muy abierta. Hay, literalmente, cientos de posibles respuestas. Suerte

Comment: Podrías incluir la definición de la tabla Transacciones y sus índices en tu pregunta? Así como la cantidad aproximada de filas en cada tabla